# str_split_fixed in an if/else statement: unexpected results

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, stringr

I have data in a data frame in the form of:

```
structure(list(O2Range = c("112 MAX", "16/19", "16/190", "12 MAX", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "16/20", "18/22", NA, "16/20", NA, 
"11/13", NA, "16/190", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As may be apparent, low and high O2 readings are separated by a '/' in the column, but occasionally it is listed as a number and then 'MAX' (ie: 112 MAX).

I am attempting to separate this column into two new columns via:

```
library(tidyverse)
data$O2High <- if (str_detect(data$O2Range, "/")) {str_split_fixed(data$O2Range, fixed("/"), 2)[, 2]
} else {str_split_fixed(data$O2Range, fixed(" "), 2)[, 2]}
data$O2Low <- if (str_detect(data$O2Range, "/")) {str_split_fixed(data$O2Range, fixed("/"), 2)[, 1]
        } else {str_split_fixed(data$O2Range, fixed(" "), 2)[, 1]}
```

However, the result doesn't turn out as expected:

```
structure(list(O2High = c("MAX", "", "", "MAX", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), O2Low = c("112", 
"16/19", "16/190", "12", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "16/20", 
"18/22", "", "16/20", "", "11/13", "", "16/190", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

There seems to be something going on with my if/else statement, but I can't work out the issue. Any ideas?

Expected Output:

```
Expected output:

structure(list(O2High = list("112", "19", "190", "12", NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, "20", "22", NA_character_, 
    "20", NA_character_, "13", NA_character_, "190", NA_character_), 
    O2Low = list("MAX", "16", "16", "MAX", NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, "16", "18", NA_character_, 
        "16", NA_character_, "11", NA_character_, "16", NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you,
Kris

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  separate(O2Range, into = c("O2Low", "O2High"), sep="/", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(O2Low = str_remove(O2Low, "\\d+\\s+(?=MAX)"),
         O2High = case_when(str_detect(O2Range, "MAX") ~ 
               str_extract(O2Range, "\\d+") , TRUE ~ O2High)) %>%
  select(-O2Range)
# A tibble: 20 x 2
#   O2Low O2High
#   <chr> <chr> 
# 1 MAX   112   
# 2 16    19    
# 3 16    190   
# 4 MAX   12    
# 5 <NA>  <NA>  
# 6 <NA>  <NA>  
# 7 <NA>  <NA>  
# 8 <NA>  <NA>  
# 9 <NA>  <NA>  
#10 <NA>  <NA>  
#11 <NA>  <NA>  
#12 16    20    
#13 18    22    
#14 <NA>  <NA>  
#15 16    20    
#16 <NA>  <NA>  
#17 11    13    
#18 <NA>  <NA>  
#19 16    190   
#20 <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. To clarify: the 'low' column should only have one value (ie: 16, while 'high' has 19, in the second line).

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what to do about `MAX`, but...

```
library(stringi)
as.data.frame(data) %>% 
     mutate(o2High = stri_extract_all_regex(O2Range, "(?<=/)[0-9]+"),
            o2Low = stri_extract_all_regex(O2Range, "[0-9]+(?=\\/)"))

   O2Range o2High o2Low
1  112 MAX     NA    NA
2    16/19     19    16
3   16/190    190    16
4   12 MAX     NA    NA
5     <NA>     NA    NA
6     <NA>     NA    NA
7     <NA>     NA    NA
8     <NA>     NA    NA
9     <NA>     NA    NA
10    <NA>     NA    NA
11    <NA>     NA    NA
12   16/20     20    16
13   18/22     22    18
14    <NA>     NA    NA
15   16/20     20    16
16    <NA>     NA    NA
17   11/13     13    11
18    <NA>     NA    NA
19  16/190    190    16
20    <NA>     NA    NA
```

OR

```
as.data.frame(df) %>% 
    mutate(
        o2High = stri_extract_all_regex(O2Range, "(?<=/)[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=\\sMAX)"),
        o2Low = stri_extract_all_regex(O2Range, "[0-9]+(?=\\/)")
    )
   O2Range o2High o2Low
1  112 MAX    112    NA
2    16/19     19    16
3   16/190    190    16
4   12 MAX     12    NA
5     <NA>     NA    NA
6     <NA>     NA    NA
7     <NA>     NA    NA
8     <NA>     NA    NA
9     <NA>     NA    NA
10    <NA>     NA    NA
11    <NA>     NA    NA
12   16/20     20    16
13   18/22     22    18
14    <NA>     NA    NA
15   16/20     20    16
16    <NA>     NA    NA
17   11/13     13    11
18    <NA>     NA    NA
19  16/190    190    16
20    <NA>     NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

using base R you could do:

```
prot <- data.frame(high=numeric(),low=numeric())
cbind(df, strcapture("(?:(\\d+)/)?(\\d+)(?: MAX|$)", df$O2Range, prot))

   O2Range high low
1  112 MAX   NA 112
2    16/19   16  19
3   16/190   16 190
4   12 MAX   NA  12
5     <NA>   NA  NA
6     <NA>   NA  NA
7     <NA>   NA  NA
8     <NA>   NA  NA
9     <NA>   NA  NA
10    <NA>   NA  NA
11    <NA>   NA  NA
12   16/20   16  20
13   18/22   18  22
14    <NA>   NA  NA
15   16/20   16  20
16    <NA>   NA  NA
17   11/13   11  13
18    <NA>   NA  NA
19  16/190   16 190
20    <NA>   NA  NA
```